# Programmatically adding shapefile to data frame in ArcMap?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, shapefile, layers

I have a toolbox with python script which creates a shapefile from JSON txt file, but it does not show the generated shapefile in arcmap, i have to add it from the output location.

What code shall I use to display this shapefile once it is created?

Answer (score 9):

There is a direct answer to your question on this link at StackOverflow:

[How do I add a shapefile in ArcGIS via python scripting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017896/how-do-i-add-a-shapefile-in-arcgis-via-python-scripting)

It is copied below with some modifications for clarity:

> Variable "theShape" is the path of the shape file to be added.

```
import arcpy
import arcpy.mapping
# get the map document 
theShape = r"C:\Data\Environmental\Floodplain.shp"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")  

# get the data frame 
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"*")[0]  

# create a new layer 
newlayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(theShape)  

# add the layer to the map at the bottom of the TOC in data frame 0 
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, newlayer,"BOTTOM")

# Refresh things
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
del mxd, df, newlayer
```

Credit to @Tom-W for the answer.